# BoxShadow only at top and bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have container, with some shadow, and I want SizedBox inside with shadow for effect, that it's inside of container. Although, the inside SizedBox's shadow overlaps the parent container shadow. How to fix this? Basically, it would be sufficient to have on child's SizedBox shadow only on top and bottom, but I didn't found a way how to do this.

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Test'),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  spreadRadius: 2,
                  blurRadius: 7,
                )
              ]),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20), child: Text('Some text')),
              SizedBox(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                    )
                  ]),
                  child: Column(children: [Text('bruh')]),
                ),
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Text('Aaaa'),
              )
            ],
          )
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```

[image: Showcase]

Answer (score -3):

If you use a css file set the style as:

```
box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888, 0px -10px 5px #888;
```

Comment: This is Flutter question, not CSS.